# How to display data object in ListBox C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have function that fills ListBox:

```
private void fillWorkListBox()
{
    this.list = manager.works();
    this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Название";
    this.listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";

    for (var i = 0; i < this.list.works.Count; i++)
    {
        string name = "№" + this.list.works[i].id + " - " + this.list.works[i].name;

        WorkModel work = new WorkModel();
        work.name = name;
        work.id = this.list.works[i].id;

        listBox1.Items.Add(work);

    }
}
```

Model is:

```
class WorkModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

When I have run project I see type of object model `work` in ListBox. Instead `name` and key as `id`.

How to fix it?

Comment: I guess that's because your `WorkModel` has neither a property called `Название` nor one called `ID`. It only has `name` and `id`. The names you give in `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` must match properties in your model.

Comment: it should be `name`, `id` from model?

Comment: yes of course, what else did you intend? but I just checked: casing is not important, so `Name` and `ID`should also work.

Comment: It  works: `  this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
            this.listBox1.ValueMember = "id";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void fillWorkListBox()
        {
            IList<WorkModel> managerWorks = new List<WorkModel>
            {
                new WorkModel {name="fooNameOne",id=1 },
                new WorkModel {name="fooNameTwo",id=2 }
            };

            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Название";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";

            WorkModel workModel = new WorkModel();

            for (var i = 0; i < managerWorks.Count; i++)
            {
                string name = "№" + managerWorks[i].id + " - " + managerWorks[i].name;

                workModel.name = name;
                workModel.id = managerWorks[i].id;
                listBox1.Items.Add("Name:" + workModel.name + "Id:" + workModel.id.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding work object directly to the list box.

Do something like below.
If you want ID to be displayed, You can append ID too (You may need to convert to string before appending)

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Name: " + work.name + "Key: " + Convert.ToString(work.id));
```

Comment: I need to set also key as `id`. This case does not fit

Comment: Append key by adding as shown . listBox1.Items.Add("Name: " + work.name + "Key: " + Convert.ToString(work.id ) );

Comment: @Daniel Edited answer for your requirement.... Ofcourse you can customize it, in whatever way you want.